# The biggest e-ink display in the world

Tags: internal-consistency, computers

**tl;dr**: *What could be an approximate size of the biggest e-ink display with current Kindle-like pixel density if we would use nowadays the biggest available computing power to make it usable?*

---

Imagine that today (beginning of 2020) you can use:

- *scenario A*: the most powerful processors cluster, stack or the fastest computer ever build,
- *scenario B*: all the computing power that human-kind currently have (when hypothetically using all computers on Earth to perform a single task),

to power, control and make usable (working, displaying something) the largest possible hypothetical e-ink display. I need to approximate the dimensions of it.

Initial assumptions:

- pixel density of current regular e-ink readers (Kindle like, so not 100 km pixel size, please),
- power issues, building problems, location issues etc. doesn't matter; only correlation between display size and computing power matters.

I am not even sure how to approach to this problem. The only thing that comes to my mind is to:

- take an average computing power of a processor powering an average e-reader (Kindle?),
- divide computing power of the most powerful computing cluster ever build by this number,
- take the resulting number and multiply it by average dimensions of an average e-reader.

Can you verify correctness of above approach and give me some resulting numbers? If not, can you answer this question using any other methodology?

**Edit**: Some clarifications, in hope to resurrect this question:

1. In both scenarios I am talking about one, single device. So, by no mean I am asking for a solutions like "video wall", "Kindle grid" or "billion of Kindles". The idea of making single e-ink display (as big as possible and answering, how large it is possible to make it), not a network, stack, rack, wall or grid of devices, is the essence of this question.
2. An example Kindle 7 has 6-inch (152 mm) display, 600 × 800 pixels resolution and has 167 PPI density ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle)). Earth surface has roughly 7.93*10^17 square inches ([source](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=2213&t=weighing-the-atmosphere)). Times 167 gives us 1.32*10^18 square pixels. Assume that I want to have a planet in similar size to Earth (or bigger, if possible) completely covered with e-ink display (irrespective of oceans, continents etc.), if possible. Do you still claim that you can make a single e-ink screen, consisted with that number of pixels, to be operable (and change the whole view "quite quickly") when you use a Raspberry Pi or similar single mobile processor to achieve that? Do you still claim that I can have that e-ink display as big as I want? Are you certain that I can change display on a hypothetical e-ink screen as big as Saturn or Jupiter surface with a single RPi?
3. I am using Kindle on daily basis. The draw-and-forget feature of e-ink displays has nothing to do with this question. Because I am clearly asking about making such extremely large display operable. You **do** need computing power for changing image from time to time.
4. I do not understand how number of viewers watching such display has anything to do with this question. I am asking about extremely large display which can change *whole* image at once. Splitting into sections or refreshing just a very tiny part of the image is out of scenarios.
5. When it comes to performance constraints, I said that it must be operable -- able to change image on the whole display "quite quickly" (in a matter of fraction of second or in similar period of time) -- as in today Kindle.
6. Again (as in 4th point) it is completely out of question and irrelevant from which distance I will be looking at this e-ink screen. It must be as big as possible (to be operable by current processors) with a pixel density similar to 150-250 PPI (or something around this).
7. Again (as above in this question), power, costs, heat generated etc. are out of question. Just the largest possible area, please.
8. Somebody said that I can't use Kindle for playing games or video. What, if I would like to achieve something similar to that? Maybe not close, but similar? What I'd like to change the whole display of such enormous e-ink screen lets say once per second? What is the largest e-ink screen with which I can do that when using nowadays most powerful processor / all processors on Earth?

In addition, I completely don't understand how this question is out-of-topic. I want to build a world in which a single planet's surface is completely covered by an enormous e-ink display. And I want to, know huge that planet can be. How can that be *not* about world building.

Comment: This is just wrong. I don't get the link between computing power and e-ink display size, and I *am* an informatician. I would have expected for the limitations on the biggest e-ink display to come from our ability to make a large e-ink display, rather than from the computing power required to draw something on it. In fact, I'm pretty sure that computing power is completely irrelevant; the very essence of an e-ink display is that it's a "draw and forget" device, so that you don't really need so much computing power as long as you can partition the display into pieces of a resonable size.

Comment: In other words, you can use a lowe-power mobile processor to drive an e-ink display of arbitrary size provided the display is cleverly made up of independent pieces the size of an ordindary Kindle display.

Comment: Do you want one continuous e-link display, or "faceted" solution is acceptable?

Comment: @AlexP If it were a single device, the bus to send video data to it would be rather extreme. However, such a display would probably be made of thousands/millions such devices that intercommunicate with off-the-shelf networking. The only real limit to size at that point is finances and engineering the scaffolding to hold them all together. It probably maxes out at some skyscraper-sized building. You could even lower QA standards, since a bad pixel (or 5000) in a 100Mx100M resolution screen is not worth being worried about.

Comment: @JohnO: That's what "cleverly made" was intended to convey.

Comment: Is this display intended to be viewed by one viewer or multiple? Worded another way, are a thousand people looking at their own section of a shared display, or more like a movie theater display?

Comment: Thank you for all the enlightening comments. Please, see the highly updated question. Does this clarify some doubts? Can such question be reopened?

Comment: As for point 4 in your edits, that concept doesn't mean as much to engineers as you might think it does.  There is little to no difference between one big screen and a lot of little ones placed side by side unless you are explicitly using a refresh algorithm that makes that distinction, such as we find with the old CRTs which must start the refresh at the top of the screen and progress downward

Comment: The entire point of a well-made video wall is that you *cannot tell* from the outside that it's made of separate pieces. What is the justification of clarification point 1? It looks to me like what a corrupt state-run purchasing authority would write in a bent public tender; that is, you are introducing a limitation which is no way, shape or form observable from outside the device. And yes, a video wall *is* a "single device". (And the original question did not contain anything about a refresh rate; once per year is still *operable*.)

Comment: As long as your display isn't bigger than the surface area of earth, you shouldn't have a problem. We have a *lot* of computing power available to us and displaying a 2d image, even a gigantic one would be possible provided the system is built efficiently and we have means to store the image (or it's computationally generated like a fractal). From an engineering perspective, this would be very difficult though

Comment: I'd say that your question is off topic pretty much because you actually answer it yourself. You say *I want to build a world in which a single planet's surface is completely covered by an enormous e-ink display.*  So in what way is "the size of the planet's surface is the size of the display" not the answer to the question?  I'm sure you're overthinking this! Just find out the surface area of your fictional world and, Bob's your uncle! You've got your answer to how big a planet surface covering display is. We don't do maths questions, so you'll have to plug in the numbers yourself. (cont.)

Comment: ...And even if it is just barely on topic, it's still not a very good question, if you take my meaning. Your query really just boils down to "how big is my planet?" And that's a question we really can't answer. Only you have access to that piece of information. It has elements of pure math questions; it has elements of plot / story based questions; you've got two different scenarios, which is really asking two different questions, but sneaky. I'd say at best the question lacks focus and probably should be closed again.

Comment: Not to mention it's considered bad form to edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers...

Comment: I strongly suggest that unless you are writing strictly for today, don't use a specific technology.

Comment: If you are literally trying to blanket a planet, your practical limitation is going to be light speed lag. If you're playing a canned video, you can probably figure out how to keep things in sync. Otherwise, practically speaking, the size limit is going to be on the order of c/k·r, where **r** is your target refresh rate and **k** is your overhead factor; call that maybe 10. So, a guesstimate might be 300km for a 100Hz display. You'll also want to artificially delay some updates so all parts repaint at the same time. BTW, this is for *any* display tech, unless you have FTL signalling.

Comment: Again, thank you for all the enlightening comments and clarification. I can now clearly and easily agree that even after editing the question is of a poor quality and must remain closed.

Answer (score 7):

Ever seen a video wall?  Multiple screens, mounted together as closely as possible and treated as a single display?

There's no reason multiple e-ink panels identical to the one in a Paper White couldn't be mounted that way.  Then it's just a matter of control.

An individual computer can control multiple display adapters, and each display adapter can manage a number of modern monitors (around 2-8 megapixels per screen), so *with no change in technology* other than a custom mount and some cables, a single modern computer ought to be able to manage an e-ink display of AT LEAST around 64 megapixels and update it as rapidly as e-ink can respond.  Now, network, say, a dozen computers together -- still with nothing proprietary except the software to let them coordinate their shared super-display -- and you'd be into the gigapixel range.  With Kindle type panels, that'll be around three by six meters, and could be managed by a single rack of server type computers the size of a small filing cabinet.

Given the displays are single-bit depth (i.e. each pixel is on or off, rather than having 24 bits of color information), with custom display adapters, each adapter could handle approximately twenty times as many display pixels; that would push your overall display size (still driven by a filing cabinet size "supercomputer") to as much as twelve by thirty meters -- still at nearly laser print resolution.

Comment: E-ink displays are draw-and-forget devices. You don't need a rack full of severs to drive a video wall made of e-ink displays, a 1.5 watt Celeron processor is more than enough.

Comment: I was working on the assumption of real-time updating -- as you noted, if you just want to draw and forget, even the Kindle's processor and OS, with minor display driver changes, could address and update an immense display.

Comment: An e-ink display *cannot* be updated in real time. That's the entire thing with e-ink displays; what you draw stays drawn until explicitly deleted. Their update time is atrocious.

Comment: I started using computers when "update time' was the two minutes or so it took a teletype to print a page of text.  Further, the page turn time on a Kindle Paper White isn't terrible -- a small fraction of a second.  Redrawing at, say, five frames a second would be close enough to real time for applications that don't depend on video frame rates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, see the highly updated question. Does this clarify some doubts? Can such question be reopened?

Answer (score 5):

As AlexP pust in his comments, this question makes no sense. And from the assumptions, I imagine you probably never used a Kindle.

The coolest thing about E-ink technology is how it takes no power to keep the screen as is. Once you update a pixel, it stays that way until you update it again. Also notice that this technology is aimed at keeping a page as it is for you to read it. It does not update multiple times per second, it updates when you change the page. TL;DR: you wouldn't use it to play games.

We can surely update faster than you can read, so scalability should be little issue. You also don't specify performance constraints, which leads us to a XKCD comic titled [A Bunch of Rocks](https://xkcd.com/505/). A few excerpts:

[image: A bunch of rocks working as a computer]
(...)
[image: A bunch or rocks working as a computer with a bug]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, see the highly updated question. Does this clarify some doubts? Can such question be reopened?

Comment: @trejder please avoid making edits that invalidate answers. We tecommend opening a new question with the new constraint if you've already got answerd and find out you need to change the constraints.

Answer (score 4):

### As big as you want

A kindle takes very little power, and we routinely pack supercomputers into areas with very high power density. Realistically speaking, we can probably manage to deliver enough power to run a moderately large e-ink display and a Raspberry PI to drive it for an array of unlimited size. (Logic behind this guess: We can turn on all the lights in an office building of very large size, and we can probably cover the equivalent of one wall of said office with power consumption in the same order of magnitude. Thus, we can probably turn one entire face of an office building into an e-ink display.)

Now, if you're willing to build the thing on the ground (i.e. so it would be viewed from the air), you can probably *literally* make it arbitrarily large, constrained by available land area. Your *real* constraint is going to be how well you can network together the individual display nodes in order to produce a coherent image. This will depend greatly on what you're actually trying to do with the thing and what your requirements are for "coherency".

TBH, given unlimited resources, I'm not seeing any particular reason why you couldn't turn, say, *the entire moon* (well, the half that faces Earth, anyway, since doing the other half might be silly) into an e-ink display with, say 100dpi or better resolution. (Why you would *want* to do so is left as an exercise for the reader, as is how to power the thing.)

---

Realistically, the short answer is that your real limits are the framework to support the displays, and, of course, *paying* for the darned thing. This goes for full-color displays, also, although at some point you may need to start incorporating active cooling systems (and I don't mean just fans).

If you want a different answer, you need to more clearly specify your constraints.

---

#### Edit, taking into account edits made to the question...

First of all, I want to make something clear. You ***WILL*** build this display out of many smaller panels. There is no non-insane reason not to do so, and in practice you won't be able to tell the difference. (Especially at the point you have the tech that you are *literally* building a planet-size display.) Trying to manufacture a *single* panel with no "dead pixels" is statistically impossible with current technology. Moreover, the bandwidth to drive such a monstrosity would be insane. Recent history has taught us well that parallelism is the way to go. This monstrous display will consist of many, *many* individually controlled units, each one possibly having its own processor to drive it.

Now... if you just want to play pre-recorded video, you should be all set! The engineering challenges are going to be "interesting", but shouldn't be insurmountable, and anyway you said you don't care about that.

Your *real* problem is going to be if you want the thing to be interactive and low latency, because at the sizes you're contemplating, speed of light limitations are going to come into play. (Unless you have FTL signalling, in which case you're deep into hand-waving territory.)

At 100Hz, the *absolute upper limit* on size is about 3,000 km (*diagonal*, not "per side"). Any more than that, and the "near" part of the display is going to be a full frame ahead of the "far" part. In fact, you probably will want to stick to no more than half of that, or the difference is going to be noticeable. I'm also assuming essentially zero overhead from processing and whatever you're doing to distribute the signal.

The way around this is to add latency. The good news is, if you're actually trying to *look* at this display, you are probably pretty far away anyway. (OTOH, human vision can only discern a few megapixels or so, so I'm not sure why you need "Kindle-like resolution"; 1 pixel per m² is probably fine!) Unfortunately, if you're at a distance you can actually see the whole display, you probably are looking at a round-trip delay of deciseconds, at best, at which point "interactive" starts to be interpreted pretty loosely, and so additional lag you have to add before updating the "near" elements to wait for the signal to propagate to the "far" elements may not even be significant.

Anyway, hope that helps...

Comment: Step 1. Take one of these giant displays Step 2 make it play one of those videos of a fireplace Step 3 When someone inevitably makes that dumb "Well is it hot too?" joke, turn off the cooling on the display and let them roast to death.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, see the highly updated question. Does this clarify some doubts? Can such question be reopened?

Comment: @trejder It looks to me like this answer, as it is now, is a totally adequate answer to your question, as it is now. Can you explain why you're not satisfied with this answer?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there's really no limit to parallelizing the control of a large screen, so there's not really an upper limit on screen size. But just for fun, here's a dead-simple way to achieve a very large screen: collect all of the Kindle readers ever produced by Amazon (perhaps ~50 million), and mount them in a grid. Load them all with slices of the images/text you wish to display. Build a giant jig to press the Next Page button on all 50 million screens simultaneously.

Congratulations, you now have an enormous single screen made of Kindles that can display a slideshow of images/text. Assuming each Kindle is just 6" on the diagonal (some are larger), we now have an e-ink screen that has a diagonal of nearly a mile. If you want it bigger, just add more Kindles. Since each display element is independently powered and controlled, there is no upper limit on how big you can go.

Comment: Pedantically speaking, if you *don't* add in a power supply (though that should be doable), you *may* run into the problem that the first one's battery is drained before you can put the last one in place. Be sure to bring *lots* of friends to help you with set-up .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, see the highly updated question. Does this clarify some doubts? Can such question be reopened?